# Loop through each item WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have 2 Grids One Is Country and Another One is Programme. Now I would like to add combination of Country(s) or  Programme(s) into Third DataGrid selected form both.
Data Binding into dgProgramme [GridView] as follows

```
using (DataSet dataset = DBHandler.GetProgramme())
{
    dgProgramme.ItemsSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Data Binding into Country [DataGrid] as follows

```
using (DataSet ds = DBHandler.GetCountries())
{
    dgCountries.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Now I would like to add Selected Values into Third DataGrid Called gRolesForUser
Current Code Is adding Selected Values into new [gRolesForUser] grid. However its not checking the duplication that's why I am planning check if the sleeted combinations is exists than not to add into DataGrid [gRolesForUser]

```
var itemsSource = dgRolesForUser.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
if (itemsSource != null)
{
    foreach (var drv  in itemsSource)
    {
       // Here I want to check that SelectedItems not Exists into using something like follows 
       if(PersonId != [dgRolesForUser].CountryId && CountryName !=[dgRolesForUser].CountryName)
       //then add to list 
        _user.Roles.Add(
        new PersonRole()
        {
            PersonId = _user.PersonId,
            Amount = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDefaultAmount.Text) ? null : (Decimal?)Convert.ToDecimal(txtDefaultAmount.Text),
            CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)dgCountries.SelectedItems[i])["CountryId"]),
            RoleId = Convert.ToInt32(cmbRole.SelectedValue.ToString()),
            CountryName = (((DataRowView)dgCountries.SelectedItems[i])["Name"]).ToString(),
            ProgrammeName = (((DataRowView)dgProgramme.SelectedItems[j])["Name"]).ToString(),
            RoleName = cmbRole.Text.ToString()
        }
    );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
var itemsSource = dgRolesForUser.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<PersonRole>;
if(itemsSource.All(item => item.CountryId != PersonId  && item.CountryName != CountryName)
{
    // Combination does not exist, add new role here
}
```

(Guessing your `ItemsSource` is an `IEnumerable<PersonRole>`)

Comment: Having the following Error 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'All' and no extension method 'All' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hi #Fabian...
Trying ....
if (itemsSource.All(item => item.CountryName != CountryName &&
                                item.ProgrammeName != ProgrameName &&
                                item.RoleId != RoleId &&
                                item.PersonId != _user.PersonId))
                                {
                                      _user.Roles.Add(new PersonRole()
                                    {
                                        PersonId = _user.PersonId
}
Condition working first time

Comment: @user3624511 If your problem is solved, please mark this answer as correct, so people know your problem is solved.